# Using pdb to step into python library installed in /lib/python3.7/site-packages

Tags: python, pdb

I want to step into python library installed in `/lib/python3.7/site-packages` using `pdb`, but when I ran main code (that calls a module from that library), it didn't stop at that line where I put my pdb statement. The library is also written in python. What is happening? Thanks

Comment: Where is `/lib...`? Is this in a virtual environment? Do your really run code inside that environment? Where do you set a breakpoint and how?

Comment: Yes, inside an env, but basically can be anything. Simply by opening the source code on an editor and `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: There are only two possibilities: Either your code does not pass this lines of code, or you run a different Python interpreter/env. In order to debug your problem, you should provide much more details, ie absolute paths to the mentioned code, the command to run your code... but all in all - yes, that should work, this is the way I did. You could also set a breakpoint in your code, and then step through until you reach the library code.